# VB.NET How can I Split every word from a HTML streamreader

Tags: vb.net, split, streamreader

I am making a tool for my father.
*I've made a streamreader to read all the data from a page and need to paste the data into a form on his companies website. ( A link between tool and website somehow isn't possible... )*

Now I wish to split all the data from the HTML in an array so I can select which arrays to extract and to input on the other form.

Any tips on splitting data from a streamreader?

Kind regards,

Me

Comment: Don't process HTML with string operations (split, indexof, substring, etc), use HtmlAgilityPack instead.

Comment: Thank you for responding @Dai 
I've just learned how to add something through Nugget manager. Now I will read upon how to use the Htmlagailitypack :)